# How to Replace All __prefix__ Placeholder Strings within Django Formsets empty_form Elements Using Only Javascript?

Tags: javascript, django

Django formsets have an [`empty_form`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/forms/formsets/#empty-form) attribute.

> **empty_form**
>
> BaseFormSet provides an additional attribute empty_form
> which returns a form instance with a prefix of __prefix__ for easier
> use in dynamic forms with JavaScript.

The Django documentation doesn't actually say how to replace the `__prefix__` with Javascript. Several online examples show how to do it with jQuery, but I specifically want to do it with Javascript - **no jQuery**.

Here is the resulting HTML from my `{{ formset.empty_form }}`:

```
<div id="prerequisiteEmptyForm">
    <input type="text" name="prerequisites-__prefix__-text" maxlength="100" id="id-prerequisites-__prefix__-text">
    <label for="id-prerequisites-__prefix__-DELETE">Delete:</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="prerequisites-__prefix__-DELETE" id="id-prerequisites-__prefix__-DELETE">
    <input type="hidden" name="prerequisites-__prefix__-id" id="id-prerequisites-__prefix__-id">
    <input type="hidden" name="prerequisites-__prefix__-content" value="21" id="id-prerequisites-__prefix__-content">
</div>
```

Everywhere it shows `__prefix__`, I want to replace it with a number... let's say `321`.

Correct solution:

```
<div id="prerequisiteEmptyForm">
    <input type="text" name="prerequisites-321-text" maxlength="100" id="id-prerequisites-321-text">
    <label for="id-prerequisites-321-DELETE">Delete:</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="prerequisites-321-DELETE" id="id-prerequisites-321-DELETE">
    <input type="hidden" name="prerequisites-321-id" id="id-prerequisites-321-id">
    <input type="hidden" name="prerequisites-321-content" value="21" id="id-prerequisites-321-content">
</div>
```

**So my question becomes**

Using Javascript only, how do I replace a constant value ("__prefix__") with something else ("321") across several elements (inputs and labels) within multiple attributes (name, id)? Specifically, I want to do it **cleanly** for repeatability. I don't want a highly custom solution to this specific problem. It needs to be a general approach... since this is replacing a constant, surely Javascript has a clean way to do this? I'm still learning Javascript and trying to not be so dependent on jQuery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used this concept:

```
const emptyForm = document.querySelector('#prerequisiteEmptyForm');
clone = emptyForm.cloneNode(deep=true);
clone.innerHTML = clone.innerHTML.replace(/__prefix__/g, '321');
```